# How to avoid internal Nashorn classes in implementations of JSObject

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

I want to provide my own implementation of JSObject as described here: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions
JSObject is within the jdk.nashorn.api package. Unfortunately the classes of the objects you get in the api-methods are not. You get NativeArray and JO4, which are both part of the internal package. My question is, how should I handle such objects? Is it recommended to use the internal functions? Or is it possible to cast those objects to anything in the api-package?

Here is my simple example:

```
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.AbstractJSObject;

public class JacksonToJSObject extends AbstractJSObject {

    final static ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        String script = "var fun = function(obj) {obj.arrayField = [1,2]; obj.objField = {\"field\":\"test\"}};";
        engine.eval(script);
        ((Invocable)engine).invokeFunction("fun", new JacksonToJSObject());
    }

    @Override
    public void setMember(String name, Object value) {
        System.out.println(value.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }

}
```

This is the output

```
jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeArray
jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO4
```

Comment: 1. Usually internal engines return object derived from class in contract and this is normal, can be cast to "basic" class. Disclaimer: i dont know it is Yoyr case, i.e. J04 derive from JSObject

Comment: 2. I dont now how to effective "plug in" your class into engine (probably You set 2in1 question) In Groovy similar work has dynamic character

Comment: Unfortunately the internal classes do not subclass JSObject and also no other class in the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've filed a bug against JDK https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8137258 to automatically handle the wrapping. In the meanwhile, please use the workaround suggested by Attila Szegedi.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should wrap these automatically for you. In the meantime, you can pass these internal objects to `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptUtils.wrap(Object)` yourself to get back a `JSObject`. This method is idempotent if you pass it something that's already wrapped, so this solution won't break if we fix the wrapping.

Comment: The solution works fine, but again it requires me to use an internal class: because the "setMember" method comes with an Object value but "wrap" requires a ScriptObject, the value must be explicitly casted to not get a compiler error. Thus I get an import of jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject. Anyway, if the wrapping is done internally, as proposed by the bug-report, everything will be fine.